# Wiping out default text when user will enter a username

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use JavaScript to wipe out default text and allow user to enter a his choice word. How do I integrate this thing with my HTML code. I need it for testing purpose. Below is my HTML code.

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="black"><form method="get" action ="http://localhost:2013">
<center>
<font color="white" size=65>Enter Word: 

<input type="text" name="word"></font></center>
</br><center>

<font color="Green" size=65>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"></font></center><
form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the default text in your code ?

Comment: Now with HTML5 you don't need to use Javascript for this feature. Just use placeholder='default text here' in the input elements.

Comment: i need to use javascript

Comment: i did it...now please upvote me ...i got to know abt discipline at stackoverflow and how to ask for your problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body bgcolor="black"><form method="get" action ="http://localhost:2013">
<center>
<font color="white" size=65>Enter Word: 

<input type="text" name="word" placeholder='Default Text'></font></center>
</br><center>

<font color="Green" size=65>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"></font></center><
form>
</body>
</html>
```

Just add placeholder='Default Text' to your input element.

Comment: i just copy pasted your code but my browser doesn't showed the default text,however when i pasted it on online html file compiler it was working fine. Any suggestion?

Comment: make sure your doctype is of HTML 5

Comment: try it now. and what do you mean by online html compiler? a browser is all you need to use html.

Answer (score 1):

No need of much items, this will help you...

```
<form action="demo_form">
  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Your default text"><br>
  <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Your default text"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: "The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a label." — http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute

Comment: yea though using it as a label is wrong i think this post answers the question atleast.

Comment: @Quentin:man, i just plotted it to understand, i never told to use it as a label!!

Comment: Not sure why this post got downvoted, I think it offers the best answer. I believe it is precisely what the OP is asking for.

Comment: IT's not Working ON IE

Comment: @mahesh It's not supported in IE before version 10

Comment: not worked any answers above?

Comment: bro i want it tobe work on IE only coz i dnt have here chrome or firefox,coz its a production envoirnment

Comment: are u looking for this? http://labs.thesedays.com/projects/jquery/clearfield/
or
http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html